# I need help comparing arrays with error checking in Java

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I looked at a bunch of previously similar issues on here and nothing I tried seems to fix my program. I'm working on a project that is used for learning Java and I'm hung up on this one section.

I need to compare two char arrays, with error checking, and print an array of enum constants that corresponds to the chars in the first array. I've tried doing a nested for loop, enhanced for loop, tried setting it up as hashsets. I need help.

The first array of chars comes from a user input string: ex. user inputs "FFRL", it gets put into a  char array ['F', 'F' ,'R' ,'L']. The second array of chars is from assigned enum values FORWARD('F'), RIGHT('R'), LEFT('L') ['F', 'R', 'L']. Throw an error if given invalid input, such as B. Instructions suggest continue and/or break. Here's the expected testing outcome:

- input: FFRL
- output: {FORWARD FORWARD RIGHT LEFT}
- input: FFB
- output: INVALID INSTRUCTION EXCEPTION

The program does have some predefined methods but I haven't gotten much use out of them yet for the loop part of the program. Let me know if you rather see code or part of the actual instructions if i didn't present this clearly.

Comment: Please show us the predefined methods, your work and your current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, this is what you're looking for :

Enum Class :

```
public enum Enum {

   FORWARD('F'),
   RIGHT('R'),
   LEFT('L');

   private Enum(char letter) {
      this.letter = letter;
   }

   private char letter;

   public char getLetter() {
     return letter;
   }
}
```

Method :

```
public static Enum[] method(char[] input) throws InstructionException {
    Enum[] output = new Enum[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (Enum e : Enum.values()) {
            if (e.getLetter() == input[i]) {
                output[i] = e;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            throw new InstructionException();
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] input = {'F', 'F', 'R'};
    try {
        Enum[] output = method(input);
        for (Enum e : output) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    } catch (InstructionException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR !");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Looking at what you provided really helped me organize my code. I was starting to make it over-complicated. Thank you for helping better understand how to use an enhanced for loop as well as using the boolean here in this instance.